# Trying to upload image with multer and xmlhttprequest, req.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, multer

i'm trying to upload an image to my express-nodejs server with multer and `req.file` is `undefined` :

server.js :

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var multer     = require('multer');
...   
var upload = multer({ dest: './img-user' });
app.post('/api/img-user/:title',  upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.file); //form files                                                                                                                                                                                               
    console.log(__dirname);
    res.status(204).end();
});
```

register.js :

```
form.onsubmit = function () { return false };

if (xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status === 200 ){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}

fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', document.getElementById("upload-button").files[0]);

xhr2.open("POST", "http://myAPI/"+fields.username.value, true);
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", false);
xhr2.send(fd);
```

register.jade :

```
form(name='form', role='form', enctype='multipart/form-data')
  .form-group
      .fileUpload.btn.btn-primary#picture
        span Picture
        input.upload#upload-button(my-upload, file="file", type='file', name='file', accept='image/*')
```

I don't want to use the `form` html tag but the `FormData` js object and xmlhttprequest, NOT $.ajax (absolutly not jQuery).